# Flutter - Navigator.push and pop isn't working with CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

The navigator.push does not redirect me to the page that I do want to be redirected as well as the navigator.pop doesn't pop the circularprogressindicator and I am stuck there.

Here are the imports of my the file.

```
import 'package:file_name/products/widget_helper/register_ui_widget_functions.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../helper/user_registration_helper.dart';
import '../model/user_registration_model.dart';
import '../pages/home_page.dart';
```

**register_widgets.dart**

```
Future signUpUser(emailUserCtrlr, passwordUserCtrlr, repeatPasswordUserCtrlr,
    firstNameUserCtrlr, lastNameUserCtrlr, context) async {
  RegistrationUser.checkFieldValidation(emailUserCtrlr, passwordUserCtrlr,
      repeatPasswordUserCtrlr, firstNameUserCtrlr, lastNameUserCtrlr);
  RegistrationUser.confirmPassword(
      passwordUserCtrlr, repeatPasswordUserCtrlr);
  if (RegistrationUser.confirmPassword(
      passwordUserCtrlr, repeatPasswordUserCtrlr)) {
        // CricularProgressIndicator here...
    ReusableWidgets.showDialogCircularIndicator(context);
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailUserCtrlr.text.trim(),
          password: passwordUserCtrlr.text.trim());
      FirestoreUserHelper.create(UserModel(
        firstName: firstNameUserCtrlr.text.trim(),
        lastName: lastNameUserCtrlr.text.trim(),
        userEmail: emailUserCtrlr.text.trim(),
      ));
      ToastRegisterUser.registeredSuccessfully();
      // Navigator.push not working
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const UserHomePage()),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      ToastRegisterUser.emailAlreadyRegistered(emailUserCtrlr);
    }
    // Navigator Pop not working
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

Here is my CircularProgressIndicator, I put it on a function so that It could be reusable.

```
static showDialogCircularIndicator(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        });
  }
```

I have tried, removing it as a function and adding the imports by redoing it. However it couldn't still get fixed. I do not know if this is a firebase problem or just the Flutter UI.

Comment: Have you tried `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop()`?

Comment: Hello, @Burak . Yes I have tried it, but it still won't work.

Comment: You put unnecessary part of code. The problem is with UI. So show us UI code part.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are opening the dialog but not popping it, you have to close the dialog first and then pop the page screen like below.

```
 ReusableWidgets.showDialogCircularIndicator(context);
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailUserCtrlr.text.trim(),
          password: passwordUserCtrlr.text.trim());
      FirestoreUserHelper.create(UserModel(
        firstName: firstNameUserCtrlr.text.trim(),
        lastName: lastNameUserCtrlr.text.trim(),
        userEmail: emailUserCtrlr.text.trim(),
      ));
      ToastRegisterUser.registeredSuccessfully();
      // Navigator.push not working
       
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // add this line here for closing dialog

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const UserHomePage()),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      ToastRegisterUser.emailAlreadyRegistered(emailUserCtrlr);
    }
    // Navigator Pop not working
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // add this line here
```

Comment: Have you check above solution